# Unable to customize themes in wordpress after migrating to https from http

Tags: errors

WordPress database error:

> Table 'wordpress.wp_ultimatetables' doesn't exist for query `SELECT * FROM wp_ultimatetables;` made by `do_action('customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WP_Customize_Widgets->enqueue_scripts, WP_Customize_Widgets->get_available_widgets, WP_Customize_Widgets->get_widget_control, wp_widget_control, WP_Widget->form_callback, wp_ultimatetables->form`

Once i click on customize themes, page loads and the above error is received.
i have used wp clone plugin to clone my website

Comment: after converting site url from http to https the above error is coming and i am unable to access themes customize option in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Run bellow query in your MySQL:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://', 'https://') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://','https://');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://', 'https://');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://','https://');
```

Or you can Add the following code above the “That’s all, stop editing!” line in your wp-config.php file `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`

Comment: thank you, but when i ran the above query did not make any chnages, still getting same error

Comment: I've edited my answer and try to checking define code in `wp-config.php`